# bookmarksnumbered option of hyperref in beamer document

Tags: beamer, sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

I wanted to put section numbers in pdf bookmarks of a beamer document. But section numbers didn't show up. What is the problem?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{
  bookmarksnumbered=true
}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Beamer}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{World}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm using MikTeX 2.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that this is a bug in `beamer` because it does not follow the usual interface that `hyperref` hooks into. The following patch allows the `bookmarksnumbered` option to have an effect:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{
  bookmarksnumbered=true
}
% get numbering in section bookmarks
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@section}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\numberline{\thesection}\secname}}%
    {}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsection}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{\numberline{\thesection.\thesubsection}#2}}%
    {}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsubsection}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsubsection}{#2}}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsubsection}{\numberline{\thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection}#2}}%
    {}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\subsection{Goodybe}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{Beamer}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section{World}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: Result]