# Beamer - Customizing PDF Bookmark

Tags: beamer, bookmarks

I am preparing a presentation in beamer including some sections and subsections. However, I want the section numbers and subsection numbers appear in the PDF Bookmarks.
I used the following code but in the TOC, the section number appears twice.

```
\section[First Section]{\S~{\protect\ref{s1}} First Section}\label{s1}
```

How can I have the following output for the PDF Bookmarks and the TOC?
[image: Desired]

Comment: Maybe you can define a `\mysection` combining `\addcontentsline` and `\pdfbookmark`

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I found my answer here [Adjust Bookmarks numbering in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146252/adjust-bookmarks-numbering-in-beamer), thanks to **[cyberSingularity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17427/cybersingularity)**.
I am giving the codes too.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{realsection}
\newif\ifrealsection
\long\def\beamer@@ssection*#1{\realsectionfalse\beamer@section[{#1}]{}}
\long\def\beamer@@@section#1{\realsectiontrue\beamer@section[{#1}]{#1}}

\patchcmd{\beamer@section}%
    {\refstepcounter{section}}%
    {\ifrealsection\refstepcounter{realsection}\fi\refstepcounter{section}}%
    {}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@section}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\S~\numberline{\therealsection}\secname}}%
    {}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsection}%
   {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{\S~\numberline{\therealsection.\thesubsection}#2}}%
    {}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsubsection}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsubsection}{#2}}%
    {\Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsubsection}{\S~\numberline{\therealsection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection}#2}}%
    {}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section*{Cover}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Cover}{Cover}

\section*{Table of Contents}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Table of Contents}{ToC}

\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```